# Failed building wheel for pyarrow when installing Apache Superset

Tags: cmake, pyarrow, apache-superset

I am trying to pip install Superset

```
pip install apache-superset
```

and getting below error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\saurav_nimesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "c:\users\saurav_nimesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\saurav_nimesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\saurav_nimesh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Scripts\\cmake.exe' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Tried Installing Windows 10 sdk and updating Visual studio tools

Please help with basic step, I am level 0 in python doing it just to get to Superset

Comment: The error suggests the `cmake` module is missing. Did you try `pip install cmake`?

Comment: yup installed the same as well

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apache Superset is pinned on `pyarrow==0.15.1` which is not available on Python 3.8, and I don't recommend trying to get the build-from-source to work.

Please ask the Superset developers to update to `pyarrow==0.16.0` or higher. In the meantime, you can use Python 3.7 or lower.

Comment: Thanks Wes. I bumped into similar issue with apache-beam set-up.

Comment: the same with `streamlit`

Comment: FYI a small upgrade of `apache-beam` supported a new enough version of pyarrow for me... i.e. [v2.48.0/sdks/python/setup.py](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.48.0/sdks/python/setup.py#L144)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by upgrading pip setuptools wheel based on another ancient post.

pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

Re: https://github.com/pydata/bottleneck/issues/281